# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 136: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hello I am trying to read a csv file. This was my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("2021VAERSDATA.csv")

df.head()
```

and this was the error I received:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8()

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 136: invalid start byte
```

I'm not sure how to correct this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

Here are the first 3 rows of my file:

| VAERS_ID | RECVDATE | STATE | AGE_YRS | CAGE_YR | CAGE_MO | SEX | RPT_DATE | SYMPTOM_TEXT | DIED | DATEDIED | L_THREAT | ER_VISIT | HOSPITAL | HOSPDAYS | X_STAY | DISABLE | RECOVD | VAX_DATE | ONSET_DATE | NUMDAYS | LAB_DATA | V_ADMINBY | V_FUNDBY | OTHER_MEDS | CUR_ILL | HISTORY | PRIOR_VAX | SPLTTYPE | FORM_VERS | TODAYS_DATE | BIRTH_DEFECT | OFC_VISIT | ER_ED_VISIT | ALLERGIES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 916600 | 1/1/2021 | TX | 33 | 33 |  | F |  | Right of epiglottis swelled up and hinder swallowing pictures taken Benadryl Tylenol taken |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Y | 12/28/2020 | 12/30/2020 | 2 | None | PVT |  | None | None | None |  |  | 2 | 1/1/2021 |  | Y |  | Pcn and bee venom |
| 916601 | 1/1/2021 | CA | 73 | 73 |  | F |  | Approximately 30 min post vaccination administration patient demonstrated SOB and anxiousness. Assessed at time of event: Heart sounds normal, Lung sounds clear. Vitals within normal limits for patient. O2 91% on 3 liters NC Continuous flow. 2 consecutive nebulized albuterol treatments were administered. At approximately 1.5 hours post reaction, patients' SOB and anxiousness had subsided and the patient stated that they were feel "much better". |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | Y | 12/31/2020 | 12/31/2020 | 0 |  | SEN |  | Patient residing at nursing facility. See patients chart. | Patient residing at nursing facility. See patients chart. | Patient residing at nursing facility. See patients chart. |  |  | 2 | 1/1/2021 |  | Y |  | "Dairy" |

Comment: Could you copy/paste the first couple of rows from your CSV into your question?

Comment: @MartinEvans edited it to include the first 3 rows

Comment: Thanks (it would have been better just as raw CSV format rather than markup format) Is it comma or tab delimited?

Comment: Have you tried `df = pd.read_csv("2021VAERSDATA.csv", delimiter='\t', encoding='utf-8')` ? If it comma delimited, you don't need to set the delimiter.

Comment: Thank you. Just tried it and got this as an error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 49014: invalid start byte`

Comment: At position 49014 it's not going to be in the first few lines of the file, it will be deep into it.  Your first task is to get the actual encoding of the file, because it's obviously not utf-8 - at least not consistently.

Answer (score 1):

I accidentally faced the same issue while trying to load the same dataset. The code below should solve your problem.

```
df = pd.read_csv("2021VAERSDATA.csv", encoding_errors='ignore', low_memory=False)
df.head()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I read my csv file, so please try it and let me know if it works.

```
with open('file.csv', encoding="utf8") as csv_file:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
df.head()
```

If you use open(file) then it will be treated as bytes and no decoding will happen.

EDITED:

Try the following encoding values:  encoding='cp1252'  or encoding='utf-16' or encoding='ISO-8859-1'

> Or last resort is ignore the error

```
with open('file.csv', encoding="utf8", errors='ignore') as csv_file:
    df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
df.head()
```

Comment: Thank you. Gave this a try and this is the error I got: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 49014: invalid start byte`

Comment: Note that `cp1252` or `ISO-8859-1` may not generate the correct characters even if they appear to work without error.